# Refresh XML feed on click (jQTouch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, jqtouch

I recently created an xml feed -> html javascript function for an iPhone app I'm developing in jQTouch. [Original](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/use-jquery-to-retrieve-data-from-an-xml-file/) Tutorial & Code.

I was wondering if someone would know a quick and easy way to refresh the xml data (grab the feed again) when a link is clicked.

eg. 
**in the code:**

```
<div id="btns">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#feed">Go to feed</a></li> <!-- When i click this, I want the getDataFeed function to dump the data & rerun. -->
</div>
<div id="feed">
 <div id="content_from_feed_inserted_here"></div>
</div>
```

**in the javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function getDataFeed() {

    $('.loadingPic').show(); // show progress bar

    $.get('http://xxxxxxx.com/information.xml', function(d) {

    $(d).find('location').each(function(){

        var $location = $(this); 
        var the_data = $location.find('xml_data').text();

        var collected_data = collected_data += '<span>' + the_data + '</span>' ;
        $('#content_from_feed_inserted_here').empty().append($(collected_data)); // empty div first

        $('.loadingPic').fadeOut(1400); // remove progress bar
    });

}

// run on page load
getDataFeed();

// how do i also get it running when i click <li><a href="#feed">Go to feed</a></li>

});
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:
Move function getDataFeed() {..} outside de ready function and capture click event from link. set id="feed" in `<a>`.

```
function getDataFeed() {

    $('.loadingPic').show(); // show progress bar

    $.get('http://xxxxxxx.com/information.xml', function(d) {

    $(d).find('location').each(function(){

        var $location = $(this); 
        var the_data = $location.find('xml_data').text();

        var collected_data = collected_data += '<span>' + the_data + '</span>' ;
        $('#content_from_feed_inserted_here').empty().append($(collected_data)); // empty div first

        $('.loadingPic').fadeOut(1400); // remove progress bar
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // how do i also get it running when i click <li><a href="#feed" id="#feed">Go to feed</a></li>
    $('#feed').click(getDataFeed);

    // run on page load
    getDataFeed();

});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the code, the button still doesn't seem to function.  Any other ideas?

Comment: also - on jqtouch - not necessarily so, it's quite active on github, plus that would require rewriting the app.  Also unfortunately jquery mobile is still only in alpha & doesn't have static tabbars/headers, and sencha is completely different - object oriented js.

Comment: Remember add id in anchor tag. Test with firebug console opened. Any errors are showed?

Comment: Respect sencha and jquerymobile, you are right. But last beto of jqtouch is dated in October 2009. One year for a beta is a lot of time. In other hand, jqtouch is now part of "Sencha Lab", so is logic that jqtouch is not supported, no?

Comment: Actually, fixed!  Using code as above, but instead of $('#feed').click(getDataFeed()); i added onClick="getUV()" to the <a href="#feed"> link

Comment: Would rather use the id method as you have above, so i'll test this out a little, and if deadline looms, go with the onclick. :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nelga Great, Thanks? Don't mention it. ;)

Comment: Ah! Fixed.  Just needed to remove the extra set of brackets... This worked: 

$("#feed").click(getDataFeed);